# How do i send Native apps log on ELK stack?

Tags: elastic-stack

How do i send Native apps log to Log stash or directly to Elastic search?
Also can some one guide me about Kafka integration with ELK stack

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are after is filebeat. Filebeat can parse your app log and send it to logstash. Filebeat also support kafka. You can push data from filebeat to kafka and then logstash can pick it up from there

```
https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat
```

Comment: Thanks Brijesh.. but filebeat dosen't work on cloud hostings and also i want to send my native apps (Android & IOS) log to log-stash. I would like to know best ways (Architecture) to use ELK stack with and without filebeat.

Comment: you have many options, use logstash http input->Elasticsearch or kafka->logstah->Elasticsearch or  from your app directly to elasticsearch ingestion node